How to force DynamoDB to use List<Sting> instead of Set<String>
When I insert a string array column the AWS SDK insert a sring set.
Is there a way to force DynamoDb to use List instead?
{
    "pk: "test",
    "tests": ["a", "b"]

}    


I would like to have it like that


Can you share your code

I am using a lib called AWS Dynamo-data-types and adding the types option fixed my issue
dynamoDBDataTypes.AttributeValue.wrap(item, { types: { test: 'L'} });
